# JQuery load 30 images

Tags: jquery, load

I'm looking for a JQuery method or plugin to load multiple images from an array.

Assume all the image paths are in a Javascript array,

1. how can I trigger a loading event. (Gif image can be used)
2. Load all images
3. Alert user all images have been loaded and remove loading event.

I am aware of .Load (http://api.jquery.com/load/) I just cant see how I can make a practical example with multiple images.

Comment: you can use jquery preload.

have a look at this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

this isn't perfect but I think you will get the idea

```
var imgCount = numberOfImages;

    $.each(yourArray,function(index, value){
           var currentImg = index;
           $('.yourImgClasses').eq(imgCount).attr('src', value).load(function() {
            if(currentImg == imgCount-1){
                 alert('Image Loaded'); 
            }
        });  
    });
```